# is there a way to make jubula mapping external object?

Tags: eclipse, jubula

[i can't map these fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMBz6.png)
I'm using `Jubula` to automate a `JavaFX` application. When I click on the browser I can't do an object mapping to select a file or to enter the file path (I think that the new Windows doesn't support `JavaFX`).

Does anyone have a solution to solve this problem(to map the fields on the image) ?

Comment: Please include a minimum working code of what have you tried so far.

Comment: i just added an image of the fields that i can't map

Comment: I recommend you delete this question as your latter one is more specific and has an answer.

Comment: how could i delete it?